# Reducing spacing in SQL Server Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to build a report with a tablix and I'm coming out with spacing like this:

[image]

I'd much rather have spacing like this:

[image]

I've got the top and bottom padding set to 0pt in that row and it still puts in that space between the numbers.  How do I bring these numbers closer together?

Answer (score 2):

In the matrix data cell's properties - change `Can Grow` property to false

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the height of your row is bigger than the height of the text in the row, giving an area of whitespace in the row and making it look like the printed rows are further apart. Reduce the height of the detail row in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox proprties, Alignment, Padding options